# Error: @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function when call a @Composable function in the lambda function

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to call a `@Composable` function inside an another function but I'm getting the `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function` error.
I had searched about it but nothing works to me.

TaskItem call

```
    task = task,
    onItemCheckClicked = {
        tasksViewModel.onEvent(
            TasksScreenEvents.OnCheckTask(task.taskId)
        )
    },
    onTaskClicked = {
        navController.navigate(
            route = Screens.AddEditTaskScreen.passTaskId(
                taskId = task.taskId
            )
        )
    },
    onTaskLongClicked = {
        //Getting error here
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
            confirmButton = { /*TODO*/ }
        )
    }
)
```

TaskItem code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskItem(
    task: Task,
    onItemCheckClicked: () -> Unit,
    onTaskClicked: () -> Unit,
    onTaskLongClicked: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .combinedClickable(
                onClick = {
                    onTaskClicked()
                },
                onLongClick = {
                    onTaskLongClicked()
                }
            )
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                vertical = 8.dp,
                horizontal = 12.dp
            ),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                text = task.taskContent.toString(),
                fontSize = 22.sp
            )
            Checkbox(
                checked = task.taskStatus,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    onItemCheckClicked()
                }
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error specifies, you are trying to create `Composable` in a `non-Composable` function. I cannot see your full code for the `TaskItem` call, but I would follow this approach:

On the top scope of the `TaskItem` call specify:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

var showTaskLongClickDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Now when user long clicks your task update this value to true:

```
onTaskLongClicked = {
    showTaskLongClickDialog = true
}
```

Within the same scope you created your `showTaskLongClickDialog` you can successfuly show your `AlertDialog`:

```
if (showTaskLongClickDialog) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { showTaskLongClickDialog = false },
        confirmButton = { /*TODO*/ }
    )
}
```